# Is there a way to use natural language processing to determine whether the phrase shows agreement or not?

Tags: python, twitter, nlp

I am doing some research related to fake news on twitter. I have isolated timelines of specific fake news stories in python, and I wanted to find out if there was a way to determine if each the text in each tweet was agreeing with the story or refuting it, thus giving me two seperate categories that I could compare over time. I know I could look for key words like 'fake' or 'false' to help classify, however I was hoping there was a more thorough way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO question is too broad and maybe more suitable for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as You ask for general framework for text classification.

Comment: Yeah I guess. I suppose I meant if there are any training tools relevant to the specific type of classification I want to perform, or if I would have to manually create the structure and training data